# 10-cvでROC曲線を記載することを目指してます、コードエラーをご指摘お願いできますか？

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

下記コードでどこかおかしいところがあるか、教えていただけますでしょうか。
irisパッケージで10クロスバリデーションを行い、ROC曲線を記載することを目標にしています。
irisの品種を１つ消して、2クラス分類としています。
最後のAUC値が1.0になってしまい、どこかでエラーが起きているでしょうか？
Google Colabを使用しております。

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")
df = iris.drop(iris[iris['species'] == 'setosa'].index)
X = df.drop("species", axis =1).values
y = df["species"]
y = y.replace({'versicolor': 0, 'virginica': 1})
y = y.values
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
model = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators =40)
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve, roc_auc_score
score_cv= cross_val_score(model, X, y, cv = 10, scoring="roc_auc")
mean_AUC=np.mean(score_cv)
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
cv = KFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True)
probas_list = []
for train_index, test_index in cv.split(X):
    X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
    model.fit(X_train, y_train)
    probas = model.predict_proba(X_test)
    probas_list.append(probas[:, 1])
from sklearn import metrics
mean_proba = np.mean(probas_list, axis=0)
fpr, tpr,thresholds = roc_curve(y_test, mean_proba)
roc_auc = metrics.auc(fpr, tpr)
roc_auc
```

Answer (score 0):

コードにおかしいところはなさそうです。
平均訓練データAUCスコアと平均テストデータAUCスコアを出してみました。
訓練では平均AUCスコアが1.0ですが、テストデータでもそれなりの値になっているので過学習していても顕著ではないと思います。

#### 結果の一例

```
ROC-AUC: 1.0
平均交差検証AUCスコア: 0.9719999999999999
平均訓練データAUCスコア: 1.0
平均テストデータAUCスコア: 0.9880000000000001
```

#### 確かめたコード

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")
df = iris.drop(iris[iris['species'] == 'setosa'].index)
X = df.drop("species", axis =1).values
y = df["species"]
y = y.replace({'versicolor': 0, 'virginica': 1})
y = y.values
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
model = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators =40)
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve, roc_auc_score
score_cv= cross_val_score(model, X, y, cv = 10, scoring="roc_auc")
mean_AUC=np.mean(score_cv)
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
cv = KFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True)
probas_list = []
# 以下2行追加
train_auc_scores = []
test_auc_scores = []

for train_index, test_index in cv.split(X):
    X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
    model.fit(X_train, y_train)
    # 以下4行追加
    train_pred = model.predict_proba(X_train)
    test_pred = model.predict_proba(X_test)
    train_auc_scores.append(roc_auc_score(y_train, train_pred[:, 1]))
    test_auc_scores.append(roc_auc_score(y_test, test_pred[:, 1]))
    probas = model.predict_proba(X_test)
    probas_list.append(probas[:, 1])
from sklearn import metrics
mean_proba = np.mean(probas_list, axis=0)
fpr, tpr, thresholds = roc_curve(y_test, mean_proba)
roc_auc = metrics.auc(fpr, tpr)
roc_auc
# 以下4行追加
print(f"ROC-AUC: {roc_auc}")
print(f"平均交差検証AUCスコア: {mean_AUC}")
print(f"平均訓練データAUCスコア: {np.mean(train_auc_scores)}")
print(f"平均テストデータAUCスコア: {np.mean(test_auc_scores)}")
```

Comment: ご指摘いただきまして、誠にありがとうございます。
たしかに、平均訓練データAUCスコアと平均テストデータAUCスコアを出すことで、
計算式の検算になりますね！ 大変勉強になりました。
今後ともなにとぞよろしくお願い申し上げます。